# Pytest imports on top vs within a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

When I move the import of implementation module within the method in test module, the test works fine.However when I have the import on top , I get an error stating that environment variable is not found.

why is the environment variable not set when I place the import on top of the file and how I can fix it without moving the import inside a function

**Error Message**

```
test/test_engine.py:4: in <module>
    from reptar_validation_engine import get_client_id
source/engine.py:30: in <module>
    ATHENA_DB = os.environ['env']
venv/lib/python3.6/os.py:669: in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
E   KeyError: 'env'
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def env_setup(monkeypatch):
    monkeypatch.setenv('env', 'dev')
```

**Test Module - This Fails**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'source')))
from engine import get_client_id

def test_get_client_id():
    get_client_id()
```

**Test Module - This Works**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'source')))


def test_get_client_id():
    from engine import get_client_id
    get_client_id()
```

**engine.py**

```
import os

env_val = os.environ['env']

def get_client_id:
    pass
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I wanted to check why the environment variable is not set when I place the import on top of the file and how I can fix it without moving the import inside a function.

Comment: Where exactly are you setting the `'env'` environment variable?

Comment: @jwodder I am setting it in engine.py outside the method definition.

Comment: @PunterVicky: The code you've posted doesn't show you *setting* the environment variable, only *retrieving* it.

Comment: The fixtures (including the autouse ones) are executed after the imports, but you're reading the env var on module level, so it will be executed on `from engine ...` import.

Comment: Thanks @hoefling....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only place you appear to be setting the `'env'` environment variable is in the `env_setup` fixture.  Like all fixtures, the code within the fixture only applies while a test is being run.  When you try to import `engine` at the top level of your test module, no test is currently in effect, and so (unless you've set `'env'` somewhere else) `os.environ['env']` will be unset at that point.  Importing `engine` from within a test function works because, before the test function is run, the fixture gives the environment variable a value.

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish by assigning `os.environ['env']` to a top-level module variable, but you're probably going about it the wrong way.  In particular, if you set the `'env'` envvar beforehand so that module-level import works, then `env_val` will not be affected by the monkeypatching.

Comment: Thanks , this helps. I will refactor it.